# How to sorting varchar

Tags: mysql, xslt

How I can sort this list number

```
  0|1|2|21|23|23-1|23.1|23.2|23.3|3|34|4|44|C4
```

become 0|1|2|3|4|21|23-1|23.1|23.2|23.3|34|44|C4 ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How is this related to XSLT? And... what have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

You can use cast

```
SELECT* FROM YOUR_TABLE 
ORDER BY CAST(you_column AS decimal(6,3))
```

but in your list you have avlue that are not proper number  `23-1`